# go - Create a new file in a specified path

Tags: go

Trying to make a portable way to create a file in a specified directory within my $GOPATH.

```
  var FileName string = "Foci.db" 
  var Driver string = "sqlite3" 

  func Connect(fileName string) (*sql.DB, error) { 
      filePath, _ := filepath.Abs("../data/" + FileName) 
      // Create db if it doesn't exist 
      os.Open(filePath)
      // Open existing db 
      return sql.Open(Driver, filePath) 
  }
```

However, this doesn't seem to create the file in the data directory as I hoped. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Open()` won't create the file. Try `Create()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You were probably looking to use [os.OpenFile](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile)

As the other poster mentioned you can use `Create()` and then `Open()` after it's created.

If you need high specificity, `os.OpenFile` can be useful as it allows you to set the path, flags (read only, write only etc.) and permissions all in one go.

Eg.

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
if err != nil {
    //handle error
}

defer f.Close()
```